# Page object event quandry

Tags: c#, .net

I am breaking down some previous code i am having to support and was wondering what these events are referring to?

```
public CodeFormatterExtension()
{
    Page.Serving += ServingContent;
    Post.Serving += ServingContent;
}
```

#### Questions:

1. `Post` object is not recognized in the `System.Web.UI` namespace, so what should i remap this to?
2. `Serving` event is not recognized.  By signature, it should accept `(object, ServingEventArgs)`, what Page/Post event should it be remapped to?

Lastly, i am unsure what .Net library framework this is coming from as most of it just a collection of code files i am importing into a project to create a controlled dev-environment for such questions.

Comment: There is no `Serving` event in any class in the .NET framework nor is there a `ServingEventArgs` class defined.  They must be from 3rd party libraries.

Comment: ok so based on this information, i am trying to latch into these "Events" what would be the logical event, obviously abstract, to attach to in standardized .Net to account for this functionality?

Comment: I have no idea what those events do - you need to read the docs for that 3rd party library.  Welcome to maintaining someone else's undocumented code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web search for `ServiceEventArgs` pointed me to [BlogEngine.NET](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Extensions&referringTitle=Documentation).  No guarantee that it is where your code came from but an example on their site matches yours exactly.

Comment: Im actually trying to make this a generic, as i saw something similar in the `using` inclusions, i just ignored it and deleted it.

Comment: Maybe you should put it back?  Point being - you likely caused your error by trying to fix it the wrong way.  You need to understand what that code does before deleting things.

Comment: problem is if its apart of the BlogEngine.Net framework i dont have its binary reference at all.

Comment: So you have two choices - either find the binaries (you can probably download it from their site, assuming it's the same or a compatible version), or you can figure out what the code is _intended_ to do and find a different way to do it.

Comment: Yeah im trying to severe any association to any specific product.  Thanx for the response, just wanted to get others ideas on how to solve the problem.